# Machine learning - predicting multiple variables that add up to 100%

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, regression, prediction, data-science

I am working on some toy models for the current US presidential election. There are four candidates and each will win some % of the vote. Its my goal to predict each candidate's %.

So far I have tried building a data set with one learned variable (% of vote rec'd) and several dozen dependent variables. Using WEKA, I have experimented with MLP and several other learning methods. My issue, is that once I learn a model for vote %, my predictions for each candidates share of the vote never adds up to 100%.

Clearly in this case its a necessity that the total % of votes received add up to 100%. Am I approaching the problem wrong? What can I do to improve my method?

Comment: you can do normalization to standardize the data. It will ensure that % sum will be 100.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as the interdependence of the percentages don't seem embedded in your equations. If you were writing it from scratch, somewhere you would include an equation forcing v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 = 1. These are called constraints and they are used to impose some underlying physics on your set of equations that otherwise they wouldn't respect.

I don't oppose abhiieors answer however. If you have a model that seems logical to you, scaling is a fine option.

v0 = v0 * 100 / ( v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 ) etc.